# MySql Query Optimization to avoid filesort

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I would like someone to help me to optimize and avoid file sort in the following query.
Attached the screenshot of its explain

```
SELECT DISTINCT(storages.id), 
     IF(admin_approve = 1 
           OR storage_free_auctions.user_id = 167 
           OR ISNULL(storage_free_auctions.user_id), 
        auction_date, NULL) AS auction_date1
FROM user_list_storage 
JOIN storages ON storages.id = user_list_storage.storage_id 
JOIN states ON states.id = storages.state 
LEFT JOIN storage_auctions ON storage_auctions.id = (
          SELECT storage_auctions.id FROM storage_auctions 
          LEFT JOIN storage_free_auctions 
          ON storage_free_auctions.storage_auctions_id=storage_auctions.id 
          WHERE storage_auctions.storage_id = storages.id 
          AND storage_auctions.status = 'Active' 
          AND (  ISNULL(storage_free_auctions.user_id) 
                 OR admin_approve = 1 
                 OR storage_free_auctions.user_id = 167) 
          AND CONCAT(auction_date,' ',start_time) >= CURDATE() 
          ORDER BY auction_date ASC LIMIT 1) 
LEFT JOIN storage_free_auctions 
     ON storage_free_auctions.storage_auctions_id=storage_auctions.id 
LEFT JOIN storage_auction_units 
     ON storage_auction_units.storage_auction_id = storage_auctions.id 
     AND storage_auction_units.status='Active' 
WHERE storages.storage_status = 'Active' 
AND user_list_storage.user_id = 167 
AND user_list_storage.user_list_id = 3 
AND (storage_free_auctions.user_id = 167 
     OR admin_approve = 1 
     OR ISNULL(storage_free_auctions.user_id) 
     OR user_list_storage.user_id = 167) 
GROUP BY storages.id 
order by auction_date1
```

First row of the explain result is as follows.

**id :** 1
**Select_type :** PRIMARY
**Table :** user_list_storage
**Type  :** ref
**possible_keys :** idx_user_list_id,idx_storage_id,idx_user_id
**key :**   idx_user_id 
**key_len :**   5 
**ref :** const
**rows :** 64
**Extra :** Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 LEFT JOIN storage_auctions 
        ON storage_auctions.id= (SELECT storage_auctions.id 
            FROM storage_auctions 
            LEFT JOIN storage_free_auctions 
                ON storage_free_auctions.storage_auctions_id = storage_auctions.id 
            WHERE storage_auctions.storage_id = storages.id 
              AND storage_auctions.status = 'Active' 
              AND (ISNULL(storage_free_auctions.user_id)
                    OR admin_approve = 1 
                    OR storage_free_auctions.user_id = 167) 
            AND CONCAT(auction_date,' ',start_time) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY auction_date ASC LIMIT 1)
```

with

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM storage_auctions  
    WHERE storage_auctions.id = storages.id 
      AND CONCAT(auction_date,' ',start_time) >= CURDATE())
```

because your clauses in the left join are redundant and been done before, all you want there is that a record with the same id exists in the future, right?

the rest of your joins are OK. they are all based on integer columns, make sure that you index on all of these ids if they are not primary keys and runstats.